# how to boot from USB stick

Tags: usb

Just bought a brand new HP pavillion all in one desk top.
I saved the current Ubuntu to a USB stick and Im not sure once im in setup
what to do to have it boot up using the USB stick ?

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: You do not just save the ISO to a flash drive, you have to use an installer. Or if a newer UEFI system, you can extact ISO yourself. UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formatted flash drive partition & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media And when you reboot, you can go into UEFI boot menu and choose the UEFI:flash boot option.

Comment: @mikewhatever Just being verbose for OP's sake: Please follow the official guides: [Create a bootable USB stick on Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and [Install Ubuntu Desktop](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop), especially step 4 ("Boot from USB flash drive").

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to the title of the question: That's what the duplicates are for: to point people in the right direction of the solution, just like you don't add a sticker "repaired" to any of your creations in the (unlikely **;-)** ) case there would be a flaw in the composite.  **0:-)**

Answer (score 1):

Once you have made a **bootable** USB of Ubuntu installation medium, here's what you do.

You have to tell your BIOS to use the USB drive as the boot medium. This is probably not the default in a new system so you'll have to do it. Here's a link to an HP document on setting the boot order: https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c00364979.

When the computer is starting up it looks to this list of boot mediums to find which medium to try first. For example you could set the order to USB,DVD,Harddisk. The system will look down this list to find the first one with a bootable medium.

**The USB option may not appear as an option in your BIOS screen unless you have a bootable drive in one of your USB slots**. So before you start your computer, put your bootable USB drive into a slot. You have only a few seconds to press the BIOS entry key so be ready to press it right away.

Once you're in the BIOS dialog system your BIOS screens will tell you how to change the boot order. The link above will help.

NOTE that it is not enough to just copy the iso to the USB drive. You will have to use a utility that creates a bootable image. The Ubuntu site has clear instructions on how to do this. The comments to your question give many reliable sources.